# Carbonfields, undefined number of elements

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation, carbon-fields

I am using carbon fields for a wordpress plugin. The problem is that in the options there should be an undefined number of inputs.

For instance (this is a simplification), in the settings there is "people", where the developer can specify more than one people.

For instance, the fields should be:

```
- Name
  Surname
  x (delete)
- Name
  Surname
  x (delete)
+ (add new person)
```

When + is clicked, new fields Name, Surname, x should appear.

My code is now something like:

```php
 Container::make('theme_options', 'XXX')
            ->set_page_parent('options-general.php')
            ->add_tab( 'People', array(
                Field::make('text', 'xxx_name', 'Name'),
                Field::make('text', 'xxx_surname', 'Surname')
            ))
```

I want that the configuration is stored in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already the **complex** field in carbon fields.

> Complex fields act as containers to which you can add multiple groups of fields. It is represented as a table, where each row is a field group. The user is able to add infinite rows of each group. This allows to repeat a set of fields multiple times creating customizable and sortable lists. This is useful when creating image galleries, lists of data or advanced content and layout elements.

[This is the link to the documentation page](https://docs.carbonfields.net/learn/fields/complex.html)

In my case it would be something like:

```php
Container::make('theme_options', 'XXX')
    ->set_page_parent('options-general.php')
    ->add_tab('People', array(
        Field::make('complex', 'xxx-person', 'Person')
            ->add_fields(array(
                Field::make('text', 'xxx_name', 'Name'),
                Field::make('text', 'xxx_surname', 'Surname')
            ))
    ));
```